# Terence Tao Analysis 1 Excercise 8.3.2 Proof Verification

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on excercise 8.3.2 in Tao Analysis 1. This is my answer to the excercise.

The question statement is:

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be sets such that $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$, and suppose that there is an injection $f : C → A$. Define the sets $D_0$, $D_1$, $D_2$,... recursively by setting $D_0 := B\setminus A$, and then $D_{n+1} := f(D_n)$ for all natural numbers $n$. Prove that the sets $D_0$, $D_1$,... are all disjoint from each other (i.e., $D_n ∩ D_m = ∅$ whenever $n \neq m$). Also show that if $g : A → B$ is the function defined by setting $g(x) := f^{−1}(x)$ when $x \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty}D_n$, and $g(x) := x$ when $x \not \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty}D_n$, then $g$ does indeed map $A$ to $B$ and is a bijection between the two. In particular, $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality.

My work:

1. The first step is to prove all the sets are disjoint from each other. Assume there are two sets $D_{n_0}$ and $D_{m_0}$ are not disjoint. The aim is to prove this contradicts the injectivity of $f$.
   Assume without loss of generality that $n_0 > m_0$. Define the two sequences $\{n_{k}:k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$} and $\{m_{k}:k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$} as follows: $n_k = n-k$, $m_k = m-k$. Consider $D_{n_1}$ and $D_{m_1}$. If they are disjoint, stop here, if not, consider $D_{n_2}$ and $D_{m_2}$ and then $D_{n_3}$ and $D_{m_3}$, etc... until for some $k$, we find that $D_{n_k}$ and $D_{m_k}$ are disjoint (and such a k does exist, because if $D_{n_k}$ and $D_{m_k}$ are not disjoint for all $k<m$, then for $k=m$, we have the two sets $D_{n_m}$ and $D_0$ which are certainly disjoint). Now we have arrived at the following: For the $k$ that was found, $D_{n_{k-1}} \cap D_{m_{k-1}} \neq \phi$ and $D_{n_{k}} \cap D_{m_{k}} = \phi$. So we have an $x$ such that $x \in D_{n_{k-1}}$ and $x \in D_{m_{k-1}}$ and so $x = f(y_1) = f(y_2)$ for some $y_1 \in D_{n_k}$ and $y_2 \in D_{m_k}$. Since $D_{n_{k}} \cap D_{m_{k}} = \phi$, $y_1 \neq y_2$. We have found that $y_1 \neq y_2$ with $f(y_1) = f(y_2)$, contradicting the injectivity of $f$. So all the sets are piecewise disjoint.
2. Next, given the function $g: A → B$, need to prove $g$ is both injective and surjective. For injectivity, if $x_1 \neq x_2$, then there are four possible cases: 
    $\quad$ 1) $x_1 \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ and $x_2 \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$. 
    $\quad$ 2) $x_1 \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ and $x_2 \not \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ 
    $\quad$ 3) $x_1 \not \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ and $x_2 \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ 
    $\quad$ 4) $x_1 \not \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ and $x_2 \not \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ 
    In the first case, $g(x_1) = f^{-1}(x_1)$ and $g(x_2) = f^{-1}(x_2)$. Clearly, $g(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$ or else the same element would map to two different images under $f$. In the second case, $g(x_1) = f^{-1}(x_1) \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ and $g(x_2) = x_2 \not \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ so $g(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$. The third case is similar to the second case, so its omitted. In the last case, $g(x_1) = x_1$ and $g(x_2) = x_2$ so $g(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$. This proves that $x_1 \neq x_2 \implies g(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$ and $g$ is injective. To prove $g$ is surjective, let $x \in B$. Then  $x \in B \setminus A$ or $x \in A$. If $x \in B \setminus A = D_0$, then $\exists y_1 \in D_1$ such that $f(x)=y_1$ and $x = f^{-1}(y_1)$ so $x = g(y_1)$. If $x \in A$, then $x \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$ or $x \not \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$. If $x \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$, then $x \in D_n$ for some  and there exists a $y \in D_{n+1}$ such that $y = f(x)$ so that $x = f^{-1}(y)$ and $x = g(y)$. If $x \not \in \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} D_n$, then $g(x) = x$. This shows that for every $x \in B$, there exists a corresponding $y \in A$ such that $x = g(y)$, and $g$ is surjective.

Is this correct? Thanks for your time.

Comment: It sounds good.